# gulp-sass starts and ends successfully but no .css files are emitted

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-sass

I have a gulpfile.js at the root of my project.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('compile-sass'), () => {
  gulp.src('./client-assets/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ includePaths: ['../../node_modules/bootstrap-
  sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/'] })
        .on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/'));
```

I have a bootstrap-custom.scss file  located in my client-assets/sass/ directory

It just has import statements much like _bootstrap.scss would

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap-
sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins";
```

I have tried calling sass() with and without the includePaths option.

I have have the node-sass npm package installed
I tried version ^4.5.3  (latest at this time)
Then tried ^4.0.0  with the same issue.

Also, I ran the .scss file directly against node-sass in commandline and it emitted a .css file correctly.

Thanks

Comment: As specified in `.pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/'))` the **CSS** can be found in the destination directory; in this case, `wwwroot`

Comment: Was not there. I checked. Thanks

Comment: I vaguely recall there being some trouble with the trailing folder slash - try just './webroot'